# Dualboot Windows 8 and Ubuntu on separate HDD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a question on dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu. My PC has an 8 GB SSD that has Windows 8 on it and a 1tb HDD for data. I just want to know how this will affect dual boot. Can I just split my 1 tb drive and add Ubuntu as I would for a PC with only 1 HDD?

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info ). Windows8 probably does not entirely fit in your 8GB SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tell GRUB to put the boot loader on the first drive, if it asks. Should be no problem. I have done this with two fixed disks and I am not aware of a reason the SSD and one fixed disk would not work the same way.